# How to save vectors in List or Array. vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, vector

Window application. This code is to have a vector of x,y,z text boxes to make a point coordinate. When I run this code by pressing a button(in the form), it rewrites every time and does not save the old vector. It only stores current x,y,z values. I was wondering if there is a way to use a list or array to have this vector stored in the program.

```
  Public Property PointCoordinates() As Vector3
Get
    Dim x As Single = 0, y As Single = 0, z As Single = 0
    Single.TryParse(xcor.Text, x)
    Single.TryParse(ycor.Text, y)
    Single.TryParse(zcor.Text, z)

    Return New Vector3(x, y, z)
End Get
Set(value As Vector3)
    xcor.Text = value.X.ToString()
    ycor.Text = value.Y.ToString()
    zcor.Text = value.Z.ToString()
End Set
```

End Property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generic list, like this:

```
Dim vectorlist as New List(Of Vector3)   'instantiate a new generic list of type Vector3
Dim vectorvariable as New Vector3(x,y,z) 'instantiate your new Vector3 structure
vectorlist.Add(vectorvariable)           'add the newly created Vector3 structure to your list
```

To enumerate through the list, do this:

```
ForEach vectoritem in vectorlist
  MessageBox.Show(String.Format("X: {0}, Y: {1}, Z: {2}",vectoritem.X, vectoritem.Y, vectoritem.Z))
Next
```

OR

```
For i As Integer = 0 to vectorlist.Count-1
  MessageBox.Show(String.Format("X: {0}, Y: {1}, Z: {2}",vectorlist(i).X, vectorlist(i).Y, vectorlist(i).Z))
Next
```

Comment: What if I want to plot the this list of coordinate. Should I use for i = 1 To len(vectorlist) GL.PointSize(5.0F) GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Points) GL.Color3(Color.Black) GL.Vertex3(vectorlist(i)) GL.End() next I tried this and it did not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I added the ways to enumerate the list to the answer

Comment: Wow thank you so much. You are the best. I knew how to do a for loop in matlab but I was not sure how to proceed it in vb. this makes a perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic List.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Public Coordinates As New List( Of Vector3 );
```

every time they click the button

```
Coordinates.Add( PointCoordinates )
```

You will need:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
```

Comment: What if I want to plot the this list of coordinate. Should I use

for i = 1 To len(coordinates)
   GL.PointSize(5.0F)
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Points)
            GL.Color3(Color.Black)
            GL.Vertex3(coordinates(i))
            GL.End()
next

I tried this and it did not work. Am I missing something?